# Is it possible to rename a firefox tab to the link text when opened in a new tab?

Tags: firefox, tabs

I am trying to find an add-on or any other way to rename Firefox Tabs to the link text they were opened from. For example the link will say "Account Settings" and when that link is opened in a new tab, the tab title will show "Account Settings", hopefully this makes sense....

I'm hoping there is an automatic way, rather than having to open my links then go through and rename them all (using currently available add-ons), as I'm having to open and close many tabs quite often and this manual process becomes too long to manage.

Any thought on this? I'm still lost...

Comment: Any thoughts on this tricky one SuperUser fam?